# Count up timer in java not starting from 0

Tags: java, date, time, timer, simpledateformat

I created a count up timer function to use in a java swing window. The problem is time does not start counting from zero. When I start the timer, the initial time always comes with an hour ahead.

Here's my code:

```
    public static void timeRecording(){
        Date startTime = new Date();
            int delay = 1000; //milliseconds
            ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                        SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
                        Date actualTime = new Date();
                        String dateToPrint = timeFormat.format(new Date(actualTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime()));


                        //String dateToPrint = timeFormat.format(actualTime);
                        System.out.println(actualTime);
                        //actualTime
                       // String timeToPrint.timeFormat = actualTime;
                        timerLabel.setText(dateToPrint);

                }
            };
    new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();

}
```

This is the time shown at start: 
[image: Time shown at start]

Comment: Probably because your time zone is UTC+1.

Comment: @assylias 
supposedly my timezone is UTC+0 (Lisbon Greenwich). I already tryed to change the format with timeFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")) but now begins from 12:00:00

Comment: Lisbon is in UTC+1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `SimpleDateFormat` of `"hh:mm:ss"` uses `h` which, in the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) is described as:

> h     Hour in am/pm (**1-12**)

Thus your hour will always start at `1`.

You could try using

> K     Hour in am/pm (0-11)

i.e. `"KK:mm:ss"`

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that if the difference between the dates is one second, this: `new Date(actualTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime())` creates a date at 1st of Jan 1970 at 00:01 UTC.

But when you format it, the DateFormat uses your time zone (Lisbon = UTC+1) and sees the date as 1st of Jan 1970 at 01:01 UTC+1.

If you want to get the correct output, you need to set the timezone of the formatter:

```
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
fmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
System.out.println(fmt.format(new Date(0))); //outputs 00:00:00 as expected
```

Note: The correct format pattern is HH (0-23), not hh (which is 1-12).